Access cookies in NextJS callback using Vercel
Anyone know why you cannot access cookies on Vercel in a NextJS callback?
import * as context from "next/headers";
export const runtime = "nodejs";

console.log("All cookies:", context.cookies().getAll());

returns only the _vercel_jwt cookie in a callback, while otherwise working normally.
It works fine on localhost. Am I misunderstanding something fundamental?
I set them as follows:
const state = randomBytes(20).toString("hex");
context.cookies().set("session", state, {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  path: "/",
  maxAge: 10 * 24 * 60 * 60, 
  sameSite: env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "lax",
});


Cookies are set in the browser. When you send a request to the backend the browsers send the cookies automatically to the server (along with that request). Only at that time you can access that cookie.

Obviously, which is why it is weird that it does not work. I auth at endpoint X of site Y, then site Y callbacks me to url Z with some auth information in the url (to the same domain as the cookie was originally set on), however it does not send any cookies I had originally set (no matter sameSite setting), except as mentioned for a (seemingly) standard _vercel_jwt cookie. When I run NextJS on localhost this behaviour is not replicated and instead the cookies are send just fine.

You have set  httpOnly: true, while setting the cookie. Is your site running in http or https?

Never mind, for some reason Vercel still uses the vercel.app domain as VERCEL_URL, even when there is a custom primary domain. Fixed.
